# Need to show the percentage of surveys in a gauge chart

Tags: reporting, dashboard, charts

I need to show the percentage of monthly positive surveys in a gauge chart like this:
[image]

But I can't seem to show the percentage as it only asks me for Record Count or Sum of score

My report is like this:

| Survey Owner | CSAT Category | Case Number | Date | CSAT Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Pass | 111111 | Aug 01, 2023 | 5 |
| Henry | Pass | 22222 | Aug 02, 2023 | 4 |
| Jude | Fail | 33333 | Aug 03, 2023 | 1 |

CSAT Categories - [5, 4] = Pass; [1, 2, 3] = Fail.

And from the sample report my CSAT score is 66.66% = 2/3

Comment: Where's the percentage in your source data (report)? Start with that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bucket field in the report, naming the pass and fail values. Then, you should be able to create a report formula to get the pass and total count to divide, and that formula should be available on the dashboard.

Comment: I'm currently mobile, but I'll update this answer when I get home tonight.